# How to process html form only by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I try to make ajax form.

```
 <form id="online_form" name="online_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate_form ( )">
 ... bif form fields...
 <button type="submit" onclick="sendMail()">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

I want to process data only by JavaScript, but when I click first JavaScript function `sendMail()` executes and after I redirected to same page with `GET` parameters like this.

```
http://my-site/?brand=Alfa+Romeo&model=147&year=2001&engine=1.6+i&box=%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%9F%D0%9F&status=%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9+%28%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85.+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%29&amount=454&name=44&phone=44&email=&etc=
```

For clarity its WordPress. I understand that default method is `GET` and default action is self, but how to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.preventDefault()` in the form's `submit` event handler:

```
<form id="online_form" name="online_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validate_form ( )">
 ... bif form fields...
 <button type="submit" onclick="sendMail()">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

If it were me, I'd call `sendMail()` from the form's `submit` handler, and call `validateForm()` from `sendMail()`, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, its works. Sorry but its no enough reputation to vote up.

Comment: @DmitryBorovkov You have.